# Which are some of best decimation algorithm to apply on large amount of data?

Tags: .net, algorithm, silverlight, charts, large-data

We have got large amount of data points (more then 50,000) which needs to be rendered on componentone line chart (or may be telerik chart control)

This chart is to show electrical channels i.e. voltage, current, power factor etc. and user can select up-to 75 channels at one time (considering multiple devices and their associated channels)

Considering the above scenario it seems that if we render all data points as it is, UI becomes very slow or unresponsive in some case, so we are looking for some decimation algorithm which can be applied on this data points which satisfies below mentioned criteria

1. It can be consumed easily from .Net/C#
2. It should reduce number of data points which improves performance and UI should not be unresponsive
3. Chart should not get distorted or show wrong representation of data (i.e. Voltage, Current ,Power data), as it is used to analyze.

Also suggest some other method to improve chart performance if any.

Development Technologies : Silverlight, C#

Answer (score 1):

ComponentOne has a video online demonstrating how to use their Optimizer to do exactly what you are describing.  I provided a link to a video below, scroll to 44:30 and you everything you need will be there.

[Vimeo Tutorial](http://vimeo.com/15334224)

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik Chart View control has its own way of sampling and aggregating data as seen here :

http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchartview-populating-with-data-chartdatasource.html